# How can a block like /* text */ be a valid xml comment?

Tags: xml, magento, comments

A while back, I was creating a module for Magento and I was following [this tutorial](http://colourgray.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/magento-create-a-custom-payment-method/#1).

In that tutorial, XML comments are being inserted inside `/* */`. I haven't noticed it back then. So now, I was looking back at my code and I noticed that had put my comments inside `/* */` as well.

My question is, how was my XML valid and why didn't it crash all this time? Is this valid way to insert comments in XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/* xxx */` can appear in an XML file anywhere text can appear - but it isn't a comment, it's ordinary text.